# Play Framework 2.1.2 Redirect Loop

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

My Play framework application has recently developed a rather nasty redirect loop, but only on one particular page (the "about" page).  No other page has this issue, the code for the "about" page is exactly the same as all others, and it doesn't happen all of the time.

The only thing I have changed lately is (1) updated Play framework and (2) installed a filter so that when `onRequest` is invoked, if the URL is the old site URL it will redirect to the new one.  I removed this filter and still had the redirect loop present after a certain period of time.

This redirect loop does not happen all of the time, and only seems to occur after a couple days of the site being live.  Restarting the Play server fixes the redirect loop, for a while at least.

Routes file entry:

`GET         /about                                       controllers.Application.about()`

Now, I do have a couple other "about" entries in routes that look like this:

```
GET         /about/clients                               controllers.About.clients()
GET         /about/history                               controllers.About.history()
GET         /about/leadership                            controllers.About.leadership()
GET         /about/philosophy                            controllers.About.philosophy()
```

Controller Method:

```
@Cached(key="aboutPage", duration = CACHE_DURATION)
public static Result about(){
    return ok(about.render("About"));
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this may be happening or anyone experienced anything similar?

Also, can anyone provide an example of how to do this in javascript? After encountering these issues, I think I would rather do this on the client side, even if it impacts redirect time slightly.

Comment: Can you share code for your Routes file and relevant controller?

Comment: Updated to show routes and controller. Thanks.

Comment: In whitch controller's method is there the redirect?

Comment: This is weird indeed. If I were you, I would remove the filter (which you did), clean and recompile. To redirect using javascript, you could use `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';`

Comment: Thanks. I removed the filter and blocked out the other "about" routes referenced above.  So far, no redirect loop yet.  The weird part is I'm not sure where the issue is stemming from, but I'll just do the redirects in javascript from now on.  Thanks.

Comment: @MaFo - the controller is the generic Application controller that ships with a stock Play app.  My other "about" pages use a custom controller.

Comment: I think it would be better to handle this with a front-end server (Apache with mod_rewrite or something) than doing it in the app itself.

Comment: Maybe, but that isn't always possible in some setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so removing the filter referenced above does work apparently.  I also, just to be safe, commented out the other "about" routes.  It appears that a redirect filter works well, but it can cause conflicts when there are multiple levels of resources in the `routes.conf` file.  For example, "/about/us/home", etc.

Not sure if this is a bug in Play, but, for now, doing the redirect in Javascript solves my issue.